# Instantiating a class return null values

Tags: java, android

I'm making an app that needs to get the results in my MainActivity, when I call `getData()` I get the data from my instantiation, but when i try to calculate the position it returns null.

This is my `Location.class`

```
public class Location implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private  List<Integer> mTypeList;
    private  ArrayList<String> listItems;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ListView listView;
    LatLng mLatLang;
    private PlaceLikelihood pl;
    private Context mContext;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    public Location(Context context) {
        this.listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        this.mTypeList = new ArrayList<>();
        mContext = context;
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        connect();
        getData();

    }

    public void buildGoogleApiClient(){
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(mContext)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .build();
    }

    public void connect() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    public void getData() {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }

        final PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
                .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);

        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceLikelihoodBuffer placeLikelihoods) {

                pl = placeLikelihoods.get(0);
                Log.e("singleplacetype", "onResult: "+pl.getPlace().getPlaceTypes());
                Log.e("singleliketype2", "onResult: "+pl.getLikelihood());
                Log.e("singleliketype3", "onResult: "+pl.getPlace().getName());

                mTypeList = pl.getPlace().getPlaceTypes();

                //Latitude and longitude
                mLatLang = pl.getPlace().getLatLng();
                String latlongshrink = mLatLang.toString();
                Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\(([^)]+)\\)").matcher(latlongshrink);
                while (m.find()) {
                    Log.e("Test", "" + m.group(1));
                    latlongshrink = m.group(1);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < mTypeList.size(); i++) {

                    try {
                        nearestPlaces(latlongshrink, getPlaceTypeForValue(mTypeList.get(i)));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {
                        listItems.add(pl.getPlace().getName() + " " + pl.getLikelihood() + " " + mTypeList  + " " + getPlaceTypeForValue(mTipoList.get(i)));
                        Log.e("singleList", "onResult: "+listItems );
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                placeLikelihoods.release();
            }
        });


    }



    public Integer getTypes(int posicion) {
        Log.e("listType", "getTypes: "+mTypeList);
        int type;
                if(mTypeList.size()>0){
                    type =  mTypeList.get(posicion);
                }else{
            return null;
                }
        return type;
    }
```

Now, that's my Location.class, I call that class in my MainActivity like this

```
Location loc = new Location(getApplicationContext());
```

I have another class that calculates some values with the first class, so after I instantiate the Location.class I can succefull see that `getData()` is executed as it returns to me some places.

**json.class**

```
 private Integer getPosition(Location loc) {
        return loc.getTypes(0);
    }
```

so, now again into my MainActivity i'm trying to fetch te values from Location.class but from json.class, since `getPosition` does something else before it is beign executed

**MainActivity.class**

```
Json json = new Json(getApplicationContext());
Log.e("jsonClassData", "onCreate: "+json.getPosition(loc));
```

now, this line is returning null , but I dont know why since getData() have been created but getTypes have inside mTypeList that is returning 0 as size and returning null since mTypeList.size is 0

Also if in MainActivity.class I call this line it returns null too

```
Location loc = new Location(getApplicationContext());
loc.getType(0);
```

it seems getData() is not saving the values inside mTypeList

Why is this happening ?

thanks

Comment: It's not clear what `json.class` is, or what its `getPosition()` is accessing, or even where it's called, but, in the last code block you've posted, `loc.getType(0)` should be returning null because `mTypeList` should still be empty at that point, because the `PlaceDetectionApi` call you're making in `getData()` is _asynchronous_. That's why you get a `PendingResult` that you set a callback on. Also, `Location` should not extend any type of `Activity` class, since it's not being used as an `Activity`.

Comment: thanks for the advice Mike, is there anyway that i can access the variable of mTypeList and get the value of it ?

Comment: getPosition is inside json.class and it only returns the position from Location, json.class is just a class that just passes data between , i call json.getPosition so json interacts with Location and that bring me a result to MainActivity

Comment: `mTypeList` isn't going to have any values until `onResult()` runs. You can't really do anything about that. You have to wait until that happens, so you'll need to implement some sort of callback or signal to `MainActivity` to let it know when the data is ready; e.g., a simple interface, an event bus, a `ViewModel`/`Observer` setup, etc.

Comment: that was the problem, can you post is as an aswer, so i can accept it, i just created an interface and waited for the results, now its working !

Comment: Oh, I'm good. :-) It was just a simple, general suggestion. Feel free to post an answer yourself, with the details of your solution. Thanks, though. I appreciate the offer. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks so much Mike, I was struggling with this since yesterday and never figured out that it is doing an asynchronous operation on the places

Answer (score 0):

```
Location loc = new Location(getApplicationContext());
```

You are not supposed to create an activity with the `new` operator.

You should use an intent for that.

And so do away with all those public member functions.

Comment: thats the instance of Location , i just deleted the extends AppCompat since that class is just a class with a constructor

Comment: Thanks so much greenapps, I can't upvote because i'm low rep yet, but thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that `getData()` is an asynchronous operation that is waiting for the results. Now, if I don't wait for that data to be done, `getTypes` does not have any value on it. Now, thanks to Mike M. I just solved the problem using a simple `interface`.

I created an interface called PlaceSuccessListener

```
public interface PlaceSuccessListener {
    void onPlaceFound(int placeFound);
}
```

called it at the last of my pendingResult

```
private PlaceSuccessListener mPlaceSuccessListener;
```

getData();

```
            .....
            placeLikelihoods.release();
            mPlaceSuccessListener.onPlaceFound(200);
        }
```

And then in my `MainActivity` I just waited for the result to be done in order to access my data. I implemented `PlaceSuccessListener` and attached the `setInterface(this)`

```
@Override
public void onPlaceFound(int placeFound) {
    if(placeFound==200){
       Log.e("jsonClassData", "onCreate: "+json.getPosition(loc));
    }
}
```